# Rspec validates_uniqueness_of test failing with additional validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

I have 2 scoped uniqueness validations on my answer model, I am trying to test these using Rspec and the respective shoulda matchers.

As seen in the `test trace` below, the uniqueness validations message is present in the errors array however, there are also 2 and sometimes 3 other errors present; `"body can't be blank (nil)", "body is too short (minimum is 10 characters) (nil)", "user_id can't be blank (nil)"`. I'm not sure where they are coming from, as body and user attributes are set explicitly in the before block.

How can I correct these additional errors so the uniqueness test will pass?

answer.rb

```
    validates_uniqueness_of :correct, scope: :question_id, if: :correct?, message: "You can only have 1 correct answer per question"
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :question_id, message: "Only 1 answer per question per user"

    /* omitted for brevity */
```

answer_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Answer do  
  before(:each) do
    @user1 = create(:user)
    @answer = create(:answer, correct: true, user_id: @user1.id, body: "some text which is over 10 chars long")
  end

  subject { @answer }

  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:question_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:body) }
  it { should respond_to(:correct)}
  it { should respond_to(:votes_count)}
  it { should respond_to(:points)}
  it { should belong_to(:question)}
  it { should belong_to(:user)}
  it { should have_many(:activities)}
  it { should have_many(:comments)}
  it { should have_many(:votes)}
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:correct).scoped_to(:question_id).with_message("correct You can only have 1 correct answer per question (true)") }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id).scoped_to(:question_id).with_message("user_id Only 1 answer per question per user (1)") }

/* omitted for brevity */
```

Test trace

```
  1) Answer 
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:correct).scoped_to(:question_id).with_message("correct You can only have 1 correct answer per question (true)") }
       Expected errors to include "correct You can only have 1 correct answer per question (true)" when correct is set to true, got errors: ["body can't be blank (nil)", "body is too short (minimum is 10 characters) (nil)", "user_id can't be blank (nil)", "correct You can only have 1 correct answer per question (true)"]
     # ./spec/models/answer_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Answer 
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id).scoped_to(:question_id).with_message("user_id Only 1 answer per question per user (1)") }
       Expected errors to include "user_id Only 1 answer per question per user (1)" when user_id is set to 1, got errors: ["body can't be blank (nil)", "body is too short (minimum is 10 characters) (nil)", "user_id Only 1 answer per question per user (1)"]
     # ./spec/models/answer_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.31 seconds
17 examples, 2 failures
```

factory.rb

```
factory :answer do
    user
    question_id :question
    body "you need to change your grip"
    votes_count 0
    correct false
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because you're not testing @answer.  You're not defining your subject in these tests.  So it's using rspec's `subject` which by default is going to a new instance of whatever class you're describing, ie. `Answer.new`.  You either need to explicitly set the subject to @answer or explicitly test @answer.

```
describe Answer do
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:correct).scoped_to(:question_id).with_message("correct You can only have 1 correct answer per question (true)") }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id).scoped_to(:question_id).with_message("user_id Only 1 answer per question per user (1)") }
end
```

Comment: Hi Philip, This indeed makes sense, i originally had this in my test, however replacing it, unfortunately doesn't seem to get rid of the errors. I have added the subject line to the question.

Comment: Huh.  What happens if you test @answer directly?  `@answer.should...`